# How to read awscli response in shell script

Tags: json, shell, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

Want to read "Items" from the AWS CLI response. and want to write "for loop" on "Items". But I am not able to do in shell script.
The output format of AWS cli command is in JSON format.

Sh Code:

```
[ ~]$ response_scan=`aws dynamodb scan --table-name recovery-plan --max-items 10 --attributes-to-get '["job_id", "job_type", "launch_category"]'`


[ ~]$ echo $response_scan
{ 
   "Count": 166, 
   "Items": [ 
        { "launch_category": { "S": "TOT" }, "job_type": { "S": "TEST" }, "job_id": { "S": "39504214122e" } }, 
        { "job_type": { "S": "TEST" }, "job_id": { "S": "8c48-914d0aa2a186" } },  
         { "job_type": { "S": "TEST" }, "job_id": { "S": "cbd07892491d" } }, 
         { "job_type": { "S": "TEST1" }, "job_id": { "S": "7afef48b0283" } },  
         { "job_type": { "S": "TEST" }, "job_id": { "S": "7d678fab68e1" } } 
     ], 
    "NextToken": "eyJFasasaseGNsdXasasaslX2Ftb3VudCasasI6IDEwfQ==",
     "ScannedCount": 166, 
     "ConsumedCapacity": null 
}
```

Can anyone help me to iterate over response_scan["Items"] ?

**What I am doing exactly**:
I want to add field - launch_category to items/row which not have this field.
Value of launch_category is TOT for TEST and TOT1 for TEST1

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate over"? What will you do with each value?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I want to update items which not have launch_category field.

Comment: Updating items from shell scripts is somewhat messy. Have you considered using a language like Python instead? It will give you much more control, with native handling of JSON.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Yes, I know from Python (boto3). It is easy.  but try to do in shell/bash script.

Answer (score 2):

```
response_scan=$(aws dynamodb scan --table-name recovery-plan --max-items 10 --attributes-to-get '["job_id", "job_type", "launch_category"]' --query Items[].job_type.S --output text )
```

Or you can use jq to parse json - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is still working, updating here as  per AWS Documentation using `--projection-expression` is recommended instead of  `--attribute-to-get`.

> --attributes-to-get (list)

> This is a legacy parameter. Use ProjectionExpression instead. For more information, see AttributesToGet in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide .

```sh
response_scan=$(aws dynamodb scan 
--table-name recovery-plan 
--max-items 10 
--projection-expression "job_id, job_type,launch_category" 
--query Items[].job_type.S --output text 
)
```

[AttributesToGet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.AttributesToGet.html)